# Handle Ajax when network connection is lost

Tags: javascript, ajax

How to handle Ajax when network connection is lost. Ajax do not return any status and remain in the '(pending)' state.

I tried this with `$.ajax()` method

```
.error: function(err){
console.log(err)
}
```

and also tried the following on error:

```
 function makeXMLHttpRequest(url, data, callback) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log("makeXMLHttpRequest:",request)
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                //clearTimeout(xhrTimeout);   // Timeout when the  upload complete

            }
            if(request.status >= 400 && request.status <= 511)
            {
                var error = new Error(request.responseText)
                error.code = xhr.status

                request.abort();
            }
        };

request.onerror = function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
                // HTTP error (can be checked by XMLHttpRequest.status and XMLHttpRequest.statusText)

            }
            else if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 0) {
                // Network error (i.e. connection refused, access denied due to CORS, etc.)
            }
            else {
                // something weird is happening

            }

        }
```

Anyone know how to handle ajax on 'network connection lost'?

Please note: Network connection lost is not the same as timeout. On timeout, we have event available in ajax but I am not looking for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeXMLHttpRequest(url, data, callback) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.timeout = 3000; // in milli seconds, so 3 seconds to wait before it timesout
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            console.log("makeXMLHttpRequest:",request)
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                //clearTimeout(xhrTimeout);   // Timeout when the  upload complete

            }
            if(request.status >= 400 && request.status <= 511)
            {
                var error = new Error(request.responseText)
                error.code = xhr.status

                request.abort();
            }
        };
request.ontimeout = function(error) {
    //handle the timeout
};
request.onerror = function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 4) {
                // HTTP error (can be checked by XMLHttpRequest.status and XMLHttpRequest.statusText)

            }
            else if (XMLHttpRequest.readyState == 0) {
                // Network error (i.e. connection refused, access denied due to CORS, etc.)
            }
            else {
                // something weird is happening

            }

        }
```

[Refer the MDN XMLHttpRequest timeout link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/timeout)

Comment: On timeout we have functions, I am asking for event when we receive error 'network connection lost'

Comment: So there's no other way to handle this error, but to add Timeout? Ajax never show error in this state and XRH always show "(pending)".

Answer (score 0):

You can add timeout in your AJAX call. That way if you don't get response in X seconds your .success object will return with status "timeout" and you can throw in error. Example:

```
$.ajax({
url: url,
data: data,
timeout: 5000,
success: function(data){
    if(data.status == "timeout"){
        alert("Internet connection problem!");
    }
}
});
```

Comment: On timeout we have functions, I am asking for event when we receive error 'network connection lost'

Answer (score 0):

You can globally set the application behavior for offline using `offline` event

```
window.addEventListener('offline', function(e) { 
  console.log('offline');
});
```

Comment: I also tried this event, it didn't trigger in chrome browser. Also how do I trigger test network connection lost event?